# How to edit the size (or color...) of selection from user search in D3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Been wrestling this issue trying to get it to work for a while... made force network in .js file (the whole file is not included below, but the search function of issue is), but for some reason I cannot edit the fill or radius of a node entered in a search bar I added in the .html file (the goal is to make the user selected node stick out).

I was able to figure out how to get the circle element of interest with `d3.select`, but get errors when trying to update an attribute using `.style()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Have looked all over web, but all of the suggestions (`container.style("fill", "red")`) work without error in what I find.

```
function searchNode() {
                var search_query = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value; // The user entered search term.

                console.log("HMMM", node)
                if (search_query == "") {
                    console.log("Nothing tho!")

                } 
                else {
                    var selected = graph.nodes.filter(function (d) {
                        return d.id.toLowerCase() == search_query.toLowerCase();
                    });

                    selected.forEach(function(d, i){
                        var node_index = d.index

                        circle = d3.selectAll('circle')._groups[0][node_index]
                        console.log("Selected circle: ", circle)
                        circle.style("fill", "red")      
                    });
                }
            };
```

Error message:

> "Uncaught type error. circle.style is not a function"

Can supply rest of .js file if it would be helpful, but didn't want to overpost. Thanks all.

Comment: don't use library's private data like `_groups`

Comment: I was trying to get around that but dont know how to get at the circle element otherwise. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried d3.selectAll('circle').nodes()[desired node index].style() but this also yields an err...

Comment: what is `graph.nodes`?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: graph is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: I'm asking what is graph.nodes in your code; how did you define / get its value

Comment: d3.json("network_data.json") 
        .then(function(graph) {...

Comment: and then can call graph.nodes from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're trying to call d3 methods upon raw dom elements instead of the selection. D3 philosophy is to define attributes as function from data as much as possible and avoid unneeded procedural loops and what not.

Personally my approach would be by using a class -- define circle as having eg `selected` class if and only if it's datum id (or whatever field you're searching on) matches the search.

Enter 0 to 5 in the textfield below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    circle.selected {
      fill: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <input oninput="highlightMatch(this.value)" />

  <script>
    // Feel free to change or delete any of the code you see in this editor!
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 960)
      .attr("height", 500)

    var data = d3.range(6).map(function(n) {
      return {
        id: '' + n,
        x: Math.random() * 200,
        y: Math.random() * 50
      };
    });

    svg.selectAll('circle').data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', d => d.x)
      .attr('cy', d => d.y)
      .attr('r', d => 5);

    function highlightMatch(id) {
      svg.selectAll('circle')
        .classed('selected', d => d.id == id);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you sooooo much. Makes sense too. Greatly appreciated, cant upvote with new account but you saved my day